# BASH - problems assigning variable using counter in variable name

Tags: bash, variables, counter

I have a groups of files in a folder.  Each group is identified by characters 3-6 in the file name. I want to read in all the files of the group, count how many files there are, and then assign the file name to a variable made up of some letters and the counter. e.g. FILENAME$COUNTER.  My code is almost working but there seems to be a problem with assigning the counter to the variable name.

I get this error for the line with code `FILE$COUNTER=$i`

```
line 12: FILE1=5_lib1ln1_BWA_ddrot_testonl_pe12.bam: command not found
```

This is exactly what I wanted for the variable name and assignment, but its saying command not found. I'm not sure why there is a command not found.

```
#!/bin/bash
## All files from the same group have the same LIB
LIB='lib1'
COUNTER=0

for i in 5_*.bam
do
    SAMPLIB=`echo $i | cut -c 3-6`
    if [ "$LIB" = "$SAMPLIB" ]; then
            let COUNTER++
            FILE$COUNTER=$i
    fi
NUMFILES=$COUNTER
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
FILE$COUNTER=$i
```

with

```
eval FILE$COUNTER=$i
```

See [eval command in Bash and its typical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses) for more information.