# why do I have to eval to > in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash, why do I have to `eval` a variable whose value is a redirection:

```
bash> foo=echo
bash> $foo true
true
bash> foo='>/dev/null'
bash> $foo true
bash: >/dev/null: No such file or directory
bash> eval $foo true
bash>
```

How to do this without `eval`?

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses

Comment: yes I am aware of that one, I read that carefully, somehow it did not yield an answer here for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirections are simply not parsed after word splitting with a variable. Only pathname expansion and similar stuffs are recognized.

With your example, `>/dev/null` is treated literally there as if you ran:

```
">/dev/null" "false"
```

In which case, `>` doesn't have a special meaning.

That is the reason why `eval` is needed to re-evaluate the resulting arguments as a new command.   Whatever you see with `echo` is what you get with `eval`.

```
# foo='>/dev/null'
# echo $foo true
>/dev/null true
```

So sometimes you also need to quote to prevent word splitting and other expansions before evaulation:

```
echo "$foo true"
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` means evaluate, telling the shell to evaluate (or perform) the expression inside the quotes.  Otherwise it's regarded as just a literal string, likely only having meaning to the user.

If you provide more detail in your question, I might be able to help with alternative approaches.

Comment: OK, then why does `$foo true` work when foo is echo ??