# dynamically creating bash variable and accessing its value defined earlier

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

i am trying to read the value of a bash variable defined earlier , but this variable name derived dynamically.

this is the bash script i am trying to do

```
  $ mythreshold=10
  $ table=my
  $ threshold="$table"threshold
  $ echo $("$threshold")
   mythreshold
```

but when  i try to read this variable value like

```
    $ echo $("$threshold")
    -bash: mythreshold: command not found
```

however i was expecting it to print

```
  $ echo $("$threshold")
   10
```

is there a way i can get this work, it should have printed the value of mythreshold variable defined above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$()` is Command Substitution. It runs the command inside and returns the output. A variable name is not a command.

You can `$(echo "$threshold")` but that will only get the `mythreshold` back.

You need [indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for what you want. Specifically [Evaluating indirect/reference variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables).

As an example, for this specific case:

```
echo "${!threshold}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use eval command :

```
eval echo \${$threshold}
```

More details about this command can be found here:

[eval command in Bash and its typical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses)

Comment: Boo, hiss -- `eval` introduces room for bugs (including security bugs), which more conventional indirection approaches would not. See BashFAQ #48: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: ...in this specific case -- consider if `threshold` contained, for instance, `'mythreshold:-$(rm -rf /)'`. A safe indirection approach would throw an error or evaluate to an empty string; `eval` would erase your drive.

Comment: Downvoting for recommending `eval` to accomplish a task for which `bash` provides explicit support.