# How do I execute a command string in BASH?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I would like to execute the following from a bash script

```
exiftool -r -v5 -P -ext mov -ext avi -ext mp4 -ext 3gp "-Directory<MediaCreateDate" -d "/media/data/Home Movies/testdestdir/%Y/%b/" "/media/data/Home Movies/testsrcdir/"
```

I have built this by concatenating strings into a $CMDEXEC when echoing the variable it looks fine but I cannot execute it from bash script.
I tried various combinations without 
luck.

```
`$CMDEXEC` >> $LOGFILE

$($CMDEXEC) >> $LOGFILE
```

etc.

Comment: Don't put your commands into variables! See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Great link @gniourf_gniourf I will improve my script when time allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `eval "$CMDEXEC" >> "$LOGFILE"` ?

Comment: I did and is working now. I realised that I left out the E from the variable as in $CMDEXE

Comment: @SebS Good to know. But as  gniourf_gniourf linked in his comment, it is considered a poor practice to put commands inside variables. So please avoid unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. As for `` not working, `eval` causes the shell interpreter to interpret again after variable expansion whereas `` does not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses