# Bash "delayed expansion" and nested variables

Tags: bash

I was able to do the following in batch, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do this in bash and could use some help. Basically, I used a for loop and delayed expansion to set variables as the for loop iterated through an array. It looked something like this:

```
FOR /L %%A in (1,1,10) DO (
   SET someVar = !inputVar[%%A]!
)
```

The brackets are merely for clarity.

I now have a similar problem in bash, but cannot figure out how "delayed expansion" (if that's even what it is called in bash) works:

```
for (( a=1; a<=10; a++ )); do
   VAR${!a}= some other thing
done
```

Am I completely off base here?

**Update:**

So it seems that I was completely off base and @muru's hint of the XY problem made me relook at what I was doing.  The easy solution to my *real question* is this:

```
readarray -t array < /filepath
```

I can now easily use the needed lines.

Comment: [What do you want to do with this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why do you think you need "delayed expansion" in Bash?

Comment: @muru In short, I need to sort a csv.  I am trying to use a for-loop to simultaneously set each line as an array and a numbered variable. e.g.

`declare -a row#variable$n=awk 'NR==$n' /filepath`

Does this clarify?

Answer (score 3):

I think, that `eval` could help in this case. Not sure, if it's the best option, but could work.

```
INPUT_VAR=(fish cat elephant)
SOME_VAR=

for i in `seq 0 3`;do
    SOME_VAR[$i]='${INPUT_VAR['"$i"']}'
done

echo "${SOME_VAR[2]}"        # ${INPUT_VAR[2]}
eval echo "${SOME_VAR[2]}"   # elephant
```

Nice `eval` explanation:
[eval command in Bash and its typical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses)

Working with arrays in bash, would be helpful too: 
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Note, that arrays are supported only at new version of bashs.

Comment: This is bash 4.0 and greater, right?

Comment: So, to make sure I'm understanding you correctly, the echo without "eval" will only display "${SOME_VAR[2]}" as a string, whereas, eval will display the actual variable?

Comment: Not really, I didn't choose variable names too much well as I can now see. The `${SOME_VAR[2]}` is variable expansion, in this case it is value invariable SOME_VAR on index 2 (same as standard $VAR_NAME). There is placed string "${INPUT_VAR[2]}". If you want to expand that string and use as variable, eval will serve to you - evaluate normal string "${SOME_VAR[2]}" as variable, which in combination with echo shows content of $SOME_VAR on index of 2.

Comment: OK, I red it correctly once again and yes. It's exactly like that. In `${SOME_VAR[2]}` is string as variable name and if you want to use that string as variable, `eval` will server to you. 
Also looks, that support is for bash 4.0+