# How to use output directly as a command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

with this grep it shows a comand I used:

```
echo `history | grep "ssh root" | head -1| cut -c6-`
```

with this output:

```
ssh root@107.170.70.100
```

I want the output to directly execute as the command instead of printed. 
How can I do it?

Comment: remove the echo?

Comment: Pipe it to `sh` or `bash`?

Comment: @123 leaving out the `echo` does not work.

Comment: @ThomasKühn yes it would.

Comment: @123 my apologies, I mistook the `\`\`` around the command for this: `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, this can be done by using the `$()` format, so

```
$(history | grep "ssh root" | head -1| cut -c6-)
```

should do what you ask for. However, I don't think that it is advisable to do so, as this will automatically execute the command that results from your `grep`, so if you did a mistake, a lot of bad things can happen. Instead I suggest reviewing your result before re-executing. `bash` history has a lot of nice shortcuts to deal with these kind of things. As an example, imagine:

```
> history | grep "ssh root"
  756  ssh root@107.170.70.100
```

you can call this command on line 756 easily by typing

```
!756
```

It's definitely much safer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd be using the `$(cmd)` syntax rather than the `` `cmd` `` syntax. This makes it easier to nest subshells as well as keep track of what's going on.

That aside, if you remove the echo statement it will run the script:

```
# Prints out ls
echo $( echo ls )

# Runs the ls command
$( echo ls )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use eval.

```
$ eval `history | grep "ssh root" | head -1| cut -c6-`
```

From [eval command in Bash and its typical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses):

> `eval` takes a string as its argument, and evaluates it as if you'd typed that string on a command line.

And the Bash Manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

> eval
>
> ```
>   eval [arguments]
> ```
>
> The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the return status is zero.