# Use a variable for redirections in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a basic script that has something like this:

```
LOG_COMMAND=">/tmp/something.log 2>&1"
if [ "${VERBOSE}" == "y" ]; then
  LOG_COMMAND="2>&1 | tee /tmp/something.log"
fi
```

The problem is that when I use the `LOG_COMMAND` variable in my script it gets wrapped with single quotes.  For example:

```
set -v
docker build -t test:test . ${LOG_COMMAND}
set +v
```

I get the following output:

```
$ /bin/bash testing.sh -v
+ docker build -t test:test . '2>&1' '|' tee /tmp/something.log
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.
```

How can I prevent the single quotes from being included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eval command in Bash and its typical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses)

Comment: @jeremysprofile that works.  If you want you can mark it as a duplicate, but this is a pretty specific example.

Comment: So, I don't love the way SO does duplications. Basically, they tell you that duplicates aren't a mark of a poor question, but they can definitely feel that way, like the other person is saying you didn't do enough research. Duplicates exist to consolidate knowledge on a topic in one place, allowing the best answers to rise to the top with a bunch of people voting in 1 area, instead of having a bunch of mediocre answers all over the place. The question marked provides enough detail to functionally answer your question, thus your question should not have its own individual answers.

Comment: We have [Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) for this problem relating to quotes, but we really need one for shell syntax in general.

Comment: I disagree that this is a good use of `eval`. As described in [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), `eval` should only be used when there exists no other alternative -- using it for redirections would mean that code embedded in your logfile names would be executed, which is a problem if you're letting a less-privileged user run and control output for a more-privileged script. There are plenty of other alternatives for conditional logging. As such, @jeremysprofile, I question the applicability of that particular duplicate.

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (*I'm trying to put  a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*) is quite pertinent to this question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, fair. I was not thinking enough about ways to avoid eval. Both answers provided do a better job, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variables store data, not code; unless you're going to do something [evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), you can't use a variable for this purpose.** Instead, just perform the indirection ahead-of-time:

```
case $VERBOSE in
  y) exec 2>&1 > >(tee /tmp/something.log)
  *) exec >/tmp/something.log 2>&1
esac
```

...will redirect stdout and stderr for all code below them. If you only want to make *some* code subject to that, set up a different pair of conditionally-redirected file descriptors:

```
case $VERBOSE in
  y) exec 3> >(tee /tmp/something.log)
  *) exec 3>/tmp/something.log
esac
```

...and redirect the commands that you want to be subject to those logging rules to that FD:

```
something_that_should_be_logged >&3 2>&3
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple and robust solution is to put code you want to reuse in a function, rather than in a variable:

```
log() {
    if [ "$VERBOSE" = "y" ]
    then
        "$@" 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/something.log
    else
        "$@" >> /tmp/something.log 2>&1
    fi
}

log docker build -t test:test .
```

The single quotes you see are not being added in any way, they're just bash's notation to show you that the value is a literal string and not part of the command's syntax. "Removing" them wouldn't change the fact that they are just uninterpreted strings any more than `whoami() { echo root; }` makes you the super user.

If it helps put things into context, Java has the same "problem" with the same preferred solution:

```
// Works
System.out.println("hello world".replaceAll("hello", "goodbye"));

// Fails
String replacer = ".replaceAll(\"hello\", \"goodbye\")";
System.out.println("hello world" + replacer);
```