# How to execute chained commands as single argument with `$@`?

Tags: bash

I have a bash file that executes `$@` in the end

```
$@
```

And it receives chained commands a single argument.

```
./script.sh "ls && clear"
```

It executes first command & consider rest as it's arguments.
I want to execute all the chained commands as they normally execute.

Comment: You don't. `"$@"` (it should be quoted) only works because after it expands to a series of words, the shell identifies the first word as the command to run, and all the remaining words are the *arguments* to the command. Parsing of shell syntax like `&&` happens before parameter expansion, so it's too late to recognize more complicated command lines.

Comment: BTW, your code needs to be `"$@"`, not unquoted `$@`, to work correctly with arguments containing whitespace, glob expressions, or  other nontrivial content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eval command in Bash and its typical uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses)

Comment: See the `eval` built-in of bash

Comment: @Corion, I **strongly** disagree that `eval` is appropriate here. `eval $@` or even `eval "$@"` has some very buggy  behavior, because it's concatenating all your arguments into a  single string and parsing it together.

Comment: @Corion, ...consider  `./script.sh printf '%s\n' *` -- go ahead and try it as just `"$@"`, and again with `eval`; you'll see behavior that's very different. (But *don't* try  it if  you're in a directory where you don't  control the filenames; if someone created a file with `touch '$(rm -rf ~)'`...)

Comment: @Corion, ...`eval "$1"` might be appropriate (because it's passing through exactly one string to be parsed as code), especially with something like `script=$1; shift; eval "$script"` letting other arguments be referred to as `$1`, `$2`, etc., and thus providing a way to pass data out-of-band from code; `eval "$@"` basically never is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command on the sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bash -c "$@"
```

Comment: `bash -c "$@"` only runs the first argument in `"$@"` as  a  script,  then passes the remainder as  arguments to that script. That's fine for `"ls && clear"`, since it's only one string (so we're leaving the arguments for `$0`, `$1`, etc empty), but `ls foo` would need to be changed to `"ls foo"`, which arguably defeats the whole purpose of using `"$@"`.

Comment: If you execute it, you will see that execute both, at least in my terminal

Comment: Yes, because of the quotes forcing both elements into the first argv element. My point is that you made the quotes mandatory, so the way `"$@"` used to work (where you could pass multiple arguments through) no longer does. It's just like how  Python's `shell=True` ignores list elements other than the first unless the string in the first element explicitly refers to  `$0`, `$1`, etc.

Comment: See `./script.sh printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"` as an example that works with the original `"$@"`, but doesn't work with `bash -c "$@"`.

Comment: Well, my answer was with the intention to keep the public interface the author expose on the question. He wanted to execute multiple commands using one single string with double quote, so I was adjusting the answer on what he asked.

Answer (score 3):

#### Maintaining The "$@" Interface

If you want shell syntax (compound commands, redirections, etc), you need  to invoke a shell. Thus:

```
./script.sh bash -c 'ls && clear'
```

...you'll also need to change `$@` to `"$@"` (unquoted, `$@` is exactly the same as -- meaning, has all the bugs of -- `$*`).

---

If you want to pass data, do so with extra arguments out-of-band from your code to avoid security bugs:

```
dir=/tmp # but unlike eval, this is still safe with *any* directory name
./script.sh bash -c 'ls "$1" && clear' _ "$dir"
```

---

Unlike  some other approaches, this still lets `./script.sh printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"` work.

---

#### Accepting Only One Argument

Using `"$@"` promises to the user that multiple arguments will be processed; however, `eval "$*"`, like `bash -c "$*"`, discards distinctions between those arguments, whereas `bash -c "$@"` silently ignores arguments past the first unless the first argument is written with knowledge of that calling convention.

To only accept one argument, and parse it as code, use:

```
eval "$1"
```

To only accept the first argument as code, and keep subsequent arguments as `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the context of that code, use:

```
code=$1; shift; eval "$code"
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles, but arguments are not in my control.

Comment: So, what *is* the possible range of arguments? Do you **ever** need to handle more than one argument? What are the cases other than `ls && clear` that need to be correctly handled, so we can be sure we don't break them in providing something that fixes the one case you did give us?

Comment: There is only one argument, a string.  It may contain any number of commands in chain & commands can have arguments.  Ex: "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic"

Comment: Then `eval "$1"` will do; if it's guaranteed that there's only one argument, there's no reason to use `"$@"` at all. And starting an extra copy of `bash` is just silly.