# How to store echo along with its info in the variable in Linux shell script, without losing the echo keyword

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell

I am  running a particular mongo command which is not hiding the password in ps for some reason. Upon checking the mongo community they are asking us to hide the password on ps by sending the password as an input via echo command

Example

```
echo mypassword | usr/bin/mongostat --quiet -u readonly --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Now this works fine as long as the echo password is used at the start of the mongostat command, but the problem comes in when I store this entire value as a string in a variable

```
password="pass@123"
mongo_command="echo $password | usr/bin/mongostat --quiet -u readonly --authenticationDatabase admin"
$mongo_command
```

So when I execute the above script the output is coming as follows

```
pass@123 | /usr/bin/mongostat --quiet -u readonly --authenticationDatabase admin
```

It is ignoring the echo keyword and only sending the password when the $mongo_command is executed. So how can I avoid this and ensure that echo goes along with the password, then followed by the pipe (|) symbol to the mongo command so that it looks as shown below

```
echo Csco@123 | /usr/bin/mongostat --quiet -u readonly --authenticationDatabase admin
Enter password:
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize  res faults qrw arw net_in net_out conn   set repl                time
```

Thanks

Comment: The stored cmd-line is being echoed, including the pipe. Try `eval $mongo_command`.  btw - the first two `usr/bin/mongostat` are missing a leading `/`

Comment: Hi @Milag , the first two mongostat commands have a type mistake. 

Yes, I tried eval as following
mongo_command="eval echo $password | usr/bin/mongostat --quiet -u readonly --authenticationDatabase admin
$mongo_command

After this it worked and thank you very much. Could you please let me know  what this eval naturally does. I checked online about this, but couldnt understand it completely. Thanks once again

Comment: See the Q&A at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11065077/10304821)

Comment: @Milag Thank you once again :)