# How to declare variable in a script that will belong to the caller

Tags: bash, variables

as the title say, I have many variables, like 200, and I'd like to have a script just containing the declarations, appart from my bash with execute code. Would it be possible with my bash that execute code to just call a script that create the variable and that exist after?

EDIT : The site proposed that answer the questions explain the same situation, however there are really good details the people who answered here gave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script - How to reference a file for variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228345/bash-script-how-to-reference-a-file-for-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the declarations are in /usr/local/lib/myvars, start your script (after the SHEBANG line) with sourcing that file using the dot notation:

```
. /usr/local/lib/myvars
```

When you have so much vars, you must have a lot of code and some general functions. Put those in one file and include that one:

```
. /usr/local/lib/my_utils
```

And know you might be wondering: 2 includes in every scriptfile? No, you can source the myvars file in the my_utils file.

Be aware you are introducing global variables, they can be changed everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the variables to be available externally and source that file.

Example. Contents of variables.sh

```
export VARIABLE1=Value1
export VARIABLE2=Value2
.
.
export VARIABLE200=Value200
```

Contents of main script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /Pathtosourcefile/variables.sh

echo $VARIABLE1
```

This would print out:

```
Value1
```

Comment: The variables don't necessarily need to be exported. Once sourced, they will be shell variables just as if they had been declared directly in the script itself. `export` is only needed if the variable needs to be visible in a child process started by the script.