# How to get the variable's name from a file using source command in UNIX?

Tags: unix

I have a file named `param1.txt` which contains certain variables. I have another file as `source1.txt` which contains place holders. I want to replace the place holders with the values of the variables that I get from the parameter file.

I have basically hard coded the script where the variable names in the `parameter.txt` file is known before hand. I want to know a dynamic solution to the problem where the variable names will not be known beforehand. In other words, is there any way to find out the variable names in a file using the `source` command in UNIX?

Here is my script and the files.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/parameters/param1.txt
sed "s/{DB_NAME}/$DB_NAME/gI;
  s/{PLANT_NAME}/$PLANT_NAME/gI" \
  /root/sources/source1.txt >
  /root/parameters/Output.txt`
```

**param1.txt:**

```
PLANT_NAME=abc
DB_NAME=gef
```

**source1.txt:**

```
kdashkdhkasdkj {PLANT_NAME}
jhdbjhasdjdhas kashdkahdk asdkhakdshk
hfkahfkajdfk ljsadjalsdj {PLANT_NAME}
{DB_NAME}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment since I don't have enough points.
But is it correct that this is what you're looking for:

[How to reference a file for variables using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228345/how-to-reference-a-file-for-variables-using-bash)

Your problem statement isn't very clear to me. Perhaps you can simplify your problem and desired state.

Comment: Not actually.In that particular answer the programmer knew the variable's name beforehand,so he could easily 'echo' it out. What I am interested in knowing is that what if I am not aware of the variable's name, how would I print it's value.

Comment: You can't, since you're not aware. How can you know something, if you don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you try to source param1.txt.
You can try with this awk :

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {
  a[$1] = $2
  next
}
{
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) {
  b = $i
  gsub ( "^{|}$" , "" , b )
  if ( b in a )
    sub ( "{" b "}" , a[b] , $i )
 }
} 1' FS='=' param1.txt FS=" " source1.txt
```